# How can I left align after using a phantom in algorithm?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, algorithms

I have the following code :

```
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{XEdDsa Sign}
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon

$A,a \gets functionCall(5)$\;
$\hphantom{A,a}\mathllap{v} \gets hash(a)$\;
$\hphantom{A,a}\mathllap{b} \gets 15$\;
\textbf{return} $whatever$

\end{algorithm}
```

However, when this compiles i get: 
[image]

I really dislike that v and b are not left aligned here. Is there any way to fix this so that they are aligned to the left?

Comment: Does `\mathrlap{v}\hphantom{A,a} \gets hash(a)` result in the expected output?

Comment: also don't use math italic for multi-letter identifiers, it is designed to make adjacent letters separate as a prodcut of variables not a word. See spacing around fand C in particular.

Comment: Avoid loading conflicting algorithm packages. Either [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) *or* [`algpseudocode`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (together with [`algorithm`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)), but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs suitably defined `\parbox` directives. It also uses `\mathit` to type "functionCall", "hash", and "whatever".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\newcommand\myAAbox[1]{\parbox{\widthof{$A,a$}}{$#1$}} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{XEdDsa Sign}
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon

$A,a         \gets \mathit{functionCall}(5)$\;
$\myAAbox{v} \gets \mathit{hash}(a)$\;
$\myAAbox{b} \gets 15$\;
\textbf{return} $\mathit{whatever}$

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a generic solution with the `eqparbox` package: I defined an `\eqmathbox`command with a left-aligned contents, using a tag  rather than a length, and all boxes sharing the same tag have the natural width of the largest contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][A]{\eqmakebox[#1][l]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{XEdDsa Sign}
\SetAlgoLined
\DontPrintSemicolon

$\eqmathbox{A,a} \gets \operatorname{functionCall}(5)$\;
$\eqmathbox{v} \gets \operatorname{hash}(a)$\;
$\eqmathbox{b} \gets 15$\;
\textbf{return} $whatever$
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]